# Docker Laravel Mapear pasta

Tags: laravel, docker

Boa tarde.
Estou tentando criar um ambiente de desenvolvimento com sublime, docker, laravel. 
A imagem que baixei do docker hub, vem com debian, php, laravel já isntalados.
O host é windows.

Porém quando executo este comando para mapear a pasta do host com o container, a pasta do container é subescrita pela pasta do host que esta limpa:
docker run -p 80:80 -p 443:443 -v \pasta\windows\workspace\app:/var/www/laravel/app/ -v \pasta\windows\workspace\public:/var/www/laravel/public/ -d eboraas/laravel
Sei que esta funcionalidade do comando é normal.
Gostaria de sincronizar a pasta do container no host e continuar o desenvolvimento da aplicação em cima deste ambiente criado.

É desta forma que normalmente é utilizado o docker para desenvolvimento?

Obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: Uma forma que eu encontrei mas não sei se é certa, foi copiar a pasta do projeto que esta no container para o host e depois rodar o comando a cima.

Answer (score 1):

Quando você executa `docker run -v pasta_host:pasta_contêiner` você está montando um diretório no contêiner antes dele ser executado.

Quando você monta uma pasta, você acaba por esconder o que havia nela antes da montagem e que só poderá ser acessado no momento que ela é desmontada, no caso do Docker ela só é desmontada na hora que o contêiner morre.

Se você montar um diretório vazio em cima de um diretório que tinha arquivos na imagem inicial do contêiner, você não verá estes arquivos no contêiner.

Vou te dar um exemplo interessante de como isso prega peças. Vamos pensar na imagem oficial do Wordpress.

Quando você baixa a imagem oficial do Wordpress ela ainda não contém o Wordpress! Ela contém o servidor web, PHP e todos os módulos necessários para executá-lo. A cópia dos arquivos é feita através de download do site official **somente se** no início da execução do contêiner, for verificado que a pasta /var/www/html está vazia.

Se por acaso a imagem oficial do Wordpress contivesse os arquivos do Wordpress na pasta /var/www/html antes da execução do conteiner e o usuário fizesse volume da pasta /var/www/html para uma pasta local no hospedeiro vazia, ela seria montada por cima dos arquivos e ao tentar acessar pelo browser veríamos o índice do servidor web mostrando uma pasta vazia e não a tela inicial de instalação do Wordpress.

Para resolver esses casos, sugiro que você suba a imagem do docker primeiramente sem montar a pasta e então execute o comando:

```
docker cp CONTEINER:/ponto/de/montagem/interno ponto_de_montagem_externo
```

Depois disso você mata o conteiner e reexecuta com a montagem (-v).